# 'coerced to Any' but property is of type UIColor

Tags: swift, xcode, option-type

This

```
NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: view.tintColor
```

Triggers this warning

```xml
Expression implicitly coerced from 'UIColor?' to 'Any'
```

But shouldn't that warning be

```xml
Expression implicitly coerced from 'UIColor?' to 'UIColor'
```

Since this property

```
NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor
```

is of type `UIColor`?

[image: screenshot]

> **Note:** This only started happening after updating to **Swift 5**, **Xcode 10.2**.

Here's more context:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
            [
             NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40),
             NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: view.tintColor
            ], for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: In what context are you using `NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: view.tintColor `?

Comment: @Arbitur edited, thanks

Comment: Its an annoying warning I know, this warning occurs also when putting an optional value in the print() function before xcode 10.2, but now they have extended that warning to everywhere. It happens because the print() function and setTitleTextAttributes() takes Any and you pass an optional, so the optional is converted into an Any and xcode is just warning you about it.

Comment: @Arbitur If print expects `Any` it makes sense to get a warning when using optionals. I thought `NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor` is of type `UIColor`, and is not an optional. But it "is" an optional (a "!" optional), and the type `NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor` expects is actually `Any`, as it is part of a dictionary parameter of `setTitleTextAttributes`, which is of type `[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55358791/5306470).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `.foregroundColor`. It has everything to do with `.tintColor` and `setTitleTextAttributes`.

This parameter is of type `[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]`. It is not in any way considering the documentation for each key. It doesn't know or care that this should be a `UIColor`. If you passed "squid", this would compile without warning (it wouldn't work, but it would compile):

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
    [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40),
        .foregroundColor: "squid",
    ], for: .normal)
```

All it's looking at is that you're assigning `view.tintColor` to a value of type `Any`.

The problem is that `view.tintColor` is not `UIColor`, it's `UIColor!`. It's not actually possible for `.tintColor` to be nil, but it's possible to *set* it to nil:

```
view.tintColor        // r 0.0 g 0.478 b 1.0 a 1.0
view.tintColor = .red
view.tintColor        // r 1.0 g 0.0 b 0.0 a 1.0
view.tintColor = nil
view.tintColor        // r 0.0 g 0.478 b 1.0 a 1.0
```

That makes sense in ObjC, but the only way to express it in Swift is to use a `!` type. When you assign `!` types to other things, they become `?` types. And that means that you're using `UIColor?` in a place that accepts `Any` (the value of the dictionary).

Using an optional as `Any` can be dangerous because it creates a lot of weird corner cases. For example, you can't round-trip an optional through Any; it gets squashed into its base type:

```
let x: Any = Optional(1)
x as? Int? // Cannot downcast from 'Any' to a more optional type 'Int?'
x as? Int  // 1
```

There are a lot of these kinds of little sharp-edges when working with Any.

Of course you didn't *mean* to work with Any. It's not your fault. But this is why Swift is complaining.

There are several solutions, depending on what you like. You can use a `!`:

```
    .foregroundColor: view.tintColor!
```

You can add `as Any` to silence the warning:

```
    .foregroundColor: view.tintColor as Any
```

Personally I'd use `as Any`.

Or you can be elaborate and unload the value earlier (I don't recommend this):

```
let tintColor = view.tintColor ?? .blue

UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(
    [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40),
        .foregroundColor: tintColor,
    ], for: .normal)
```

Comment: Makes sense (a lot to absorb!), but why would Swift be designed like this? Shouldn't the code not compile if `foregroundColor` gets assigned to it a wrongly typed value? Also, how does it work as of now? If I pass `.red`, and the parameter is of type `Any`, how does the new value of type `Any` get translated back to a `UIColor`? Also, why do you not recommend "elaborate and unload value earlier"?

Comment: Swift isn't designed like this. UIKit is designed like this because UIKit was built for ObjC. No API intended for Swift would include an "Any" as its dictionary value. On the ObjC side, at runtime, *everything* is Any (technically closer to AnyObject, but the same point). ObjC does not have the kind of strong types that Swift does. It doesn't care if you pass a UIColor or not. It just cares that the thing you pass it can respond to certain messages in certain ways.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for the info. (I guess this should all change eventually, I.E. removing `Any` from various places in Swift?)

Comment: In this case I don't recommend adding the `??` check or an `if let` check because `tintColor` is a `!` variable from ObjC. It's never going to be nil when you read it. Using extra code to check for that case is misleading. And even if it *could* be nil, it would just work correctly anyway (that's not a general point; it just happens to be true in this case).

Comment: Ah, I was thinking something like if it's accessed too early in the life cycle, then it might be nil, as the view doesn't fully exist yet. But ok!

Comment: You should definitely pull Any out of your Swift. Unless you mean "absolutely any value here is fine, a UIViewController, an Int, a bluetooth device, *anything*" you don't mean Any.

Comment: Nah; it's defined to return a default if it's not set. But you only know that by reading the docs. (But also that particular choice is just style, and just around this precise case. Any of the answers are fine.)

Answer (score 2):

`setTitleTextAttributes` expects a dictionary of `[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]`

Everything can be treated as `Any` and **that's why this warning doesn't appear in any other case**. The only time it appears is when you do it with `Optional`. Compiler just wants you to make sure that you know what you're doing with your optional :)

**You asked why it happens in Xcode 10.2 and Swift 5?**

It always worked well for optionals that were declared this way:

```swift
let optionalNumber: Int? = 5
```

and never for optionals that were declared this way:

```swift
let implicitlyUnwrappedOptionalNumber: Int! = 5
```

look at your example:
`view.tintColor`
is

[image]

Why it didn't worked for implicitly unwrapped optionals? Because before Swift 5, `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` and `Optional` were two different types! And as I wrote before: It always worked well for **optionals** (and didn't work for `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`).

Right now they are the same type, but implicitly unwrapped optionals have special `@_autounwrapped` mechanism to differentiate the two.

Thay **started** removal of this type in Swift 4.2:

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md

> This proposal seeks to limit the adoption of IUOs to places where they
>   are actually required, and put the Swift language on the path to
>   removing implicitly unwrapped optionals from the system entirely when
>   other technologies render them unnecessary. It also completely
>   abolishes any notion of IUOs below the type-checker level of the
>   compiler, which will substantially simplify the compiler
>   implementation.

but apparently they **completed** it in Swift 5:

https://forums.swift.org/t/possible-misdiagnosis-of-se-0054/9546

> ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional isn’t going to be a type at all anymore.
>   We put the warnings specifically around the use of ! because that’s
>   easier to detect, but yes, using it in any position that isn’t the
>   top-level type of a variable, parameter, or return value is deprecated
>   and will be removed. (@rudkx has already done a lot of work to
>   actually do that removing in Swift 5, some of which will start showing
>   up even in Swift 4.1.)

Comment: _"before Swift 5, ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional and Optional were two different types"_. Aha! That's it it would seem.

Comment: Glad I could help :) It's so hard to find this kind of info without diving into Swift codebase itself. I'm still not sure if they removed `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` from Swift 100%. And yesterday I didn't even know there was such a type :)

Comment: dive where? Tell me more :)

Comment: Here: https://github.com/apple/swift and here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution aaaand here: https://forums.swift.org/

Comment: Thanks! Me gonna check me out

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
guard let viewTint = view.tintColor else { return }
NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: viewTint
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This should work, but why does Xcode expect a value of type `Any`? If you option-click on `foregroundColor`, it says it's of type `UIColor`.

Comment: The point is the type of `tintColor`. It’s an Optional. You need to unwrap it. For example `NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: view.tintColor!`. Does that fix it?

Comment: @matt yes that fixes the warning. But then the warning should be "coerced from UIColor? to UIColor". Also, this didn't happen in Swift 4.2, which as far as this snippet is concerned (and I read the docs of what's new, too), doesn't treat optionals any differently from Swift 5. My question is, why this warning? Is it a bug, or is something else wrong/changed in Swift 5 or my code?

Comment: I don’t agree but you have not provided even one line of actual code to test with.

Comment: The warning says coerced to `Any`, as the definition of the dictionary you are trying to set the value for is `[NSAttributedString.Key: Any]`, e.g. when you insert an optional it will be coerced to be `Any` instead. The text attributes dictionary cannot tell the expected type of the value from the key's value (the dictionary itself does not support it), and other text attributes would expect `UIFont`, or `NSNumber`, or `UIParagraphStyle` or similar type instances as values. Hence UIKit decided to pick the common ancestor of these types - which is `Any`.

Comment: @OkiRules the question isn't how to fix the warning. That I can do. The question is why such a warning etc (see edited question in case you didn't yet)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what [Rob Napier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97337/rob-napier) wrote in his [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55358791/5306470), here is Apple's response to my Bug Report:

> Engineering has provided the following information regarding this issue:
>
> This is an unintended result of an intentional change in Swift 5.
>   tintColor is of type UIColor!, an implicitly unwrapped optional, and
>   it needs to be converted to Any so it can be added to the dictionary
>   passed to setTitleTextAttributes(_:for:). When faced with this
>   situation, Swift 4.2 would insert a force unwrap to convert the value
>   to UIColor, which would cause a difficult-to-debug crash if the value
>   was nil. Swift 5.0 instead converts the value to UIColor?, which never
>   crashes but emits a warning when implicitly converted to Any.
>
> In your specific case, the tintColor property is documented to never
>   return nil, so it’s safe to use the force unwrapping operator by
>   writing “view.tintColor!” instead of “view.tintColor”. (This
>   workaround is specific to the tintColor property—in other situations
>   where you get this warning, force-unwrapping may crash your app at
>   runtime. Only force-unwrap when you are certain that the value can
>   never be nil.)
>
> If your project has a strict style guide which absolutely forbids
>   force unwrapping, you could instead use the nil-coalescing operator by
>   writing something like “view.tintColor ?? UIColor.black”."